# How to check if there is new data on mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I need to write a application that checks database from external server every 10 seconds to see if there is new data. Currently I have a javascript that checks if data has changed server by comparing two JSON (the old JSON and the new fetched from server) and if it has alerts user. But that is not what I need in this application. User should be alerted only when data is new, not when it has changed.

I was thinking that maybe I could do this with a PHP code that queries MYSQL and if query num_results is 0 loop until num_results is more than 0 when user gets notified. In this application it doesn't matter whether the new data is available for user in 0,1 second or 10 seconds, just as long as user gets it. This is how I tried to do the MYSQL check, but it isn't working:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

if(isset($_GET['ID'])) {
    $maxLoop = 20;    
    while($maxLoop--) {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass); 
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        try {
            $sth = $dbh->prepare('select * from testit where id = :id');
            $sth->bindParam(':id',$_GET['ID'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $sth->execute();
            if($sth->rowCount()>0) {
                $results = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                echo '{"key":'. json_encode($results) .'}';
                exit; // Found new data, end loop and script
            }
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            break;   
        }
        sleep(3);    
    } // end while
} // end if
```

So how can I alter this code to make it work, or should I just try to write some javascript that would do this? And if so, how can I check whether data is new or not, instead of just checking whether it has changed or not?

Answer (score 3):

How do you record 'new' data? is there a timestamp? an auto_increment primary key field?

The easiest method for polling is to simply keep track of the last known id/timestamp and see if there's anything with a higher id/newer timestamp.

As is, your method is quite inefficient. You select ALL records in the table, forcing mysql/pdo to start fetching that data from disk, etc... then simply throw it away after getting the row count. A more efficient method is do to a `select count(*) ...` and checking that value. This keeps mysql from having to start fetching actual row data from disk. And on some table types (myisam in particular), a count(*) operation is VERY quick.

Comment: There is a column called condition in table. So application should check if there are any rows with a condition = false. And if there are it should print them. When users sees those rows, they press a button that changes values from false to true. So every row with condition = false is considered as "new data".

Comment: and I need to display all the data for user, not just the number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your application to check for changes every 10 seconds, you will have to use `AJAX` to make `asyncronous` requests to a php file on the server. In the php file, you only have to `select * from testit where condition=false` and you will get your "new data". Here's a link from where you can learn the basics of `AJAX` : 
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp